# atmega timer strange behavior

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, atmega

I'm using `atmega8` running at `1MHz`. I wrote a function that counts the milliseconds and it was working flawlessly.

However, when I modified the code to count microseconds the result was weird to my eye, e.g. instead of blinking the LED each second, the LED was turned on for one second and then turned off permanently.

Is there anything I'm not aware of? Could it be related to the fact that `timer2` is `8bit` (some overflows happening)?

The `timer.c` (commented snippets are working)

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/atomic.h>
#include "../include/timers.h"

volatile unsigned long milliseconds;
volatile unsigned long microseconds;

ISR (TIMER2_COMP_vect)
{
    microseconds += 50;

    if (microseconds % 1000 == 0) {
        milliseconds++;
    }
}

void timers_init(void)
{
    TCCR2 |= (1 << WGM21);

    //Set the prescaler to 8
    TCCR2 |= (1 << CS21);

    //OCRn = [ (Clock / Prescaler) * Seconds ] - 1
    OCR2 = 99;

    TIMSK |= (1 << OCIE2);

    sei();
}

unsigned long timers_millis(void)
{
    unsigned long millis;

    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_FORCEON) {
        millis = milliseconds;
    }

    return millis;
}

unsigned long timers_micros(void)
{
    unsigned long micros;

    ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_FORCEON) {
        micros = microseconds;
    }

    return micros;
}
```

And calling the LED blinker

```
while (1) {
    if (timers_micros() % 1000000 == 0) {
        leds_on(LEDS_REGISTER_PORT, LEDS_PORT_LEFT);
    } else {
        leds_off(LEDS_REGISTER_PORT, LEDS_PORT_LEFT);
    }

    if (timers_millis() % 1000 == 0) {
        leds_on(LEDS_REGISTER_PORT, LEDS_PORT_RIGHT);
    } else {
        leds_off(LEDS_REGISTER_PORT, LEDS_PORT_RIGHT);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The previous code has been updated to reflect the changes in soft / hardware.

I've updated the hardware with external `16MHz` oscillator, set the fuse bits, modified the macros, e.g. `F_CPU` accordingly. Now, I just wanted to check if my counter works as I suspect but it failed - the led `RIGHT` that acquires `timers_millis()` and is supposed to turn on every second works fine but the other led `LEFT` flashes randomly. The only pattern with `LEFT` is that if it turns on the `RIGHT` is on as well.

I've run out of ideas and solutions. What could be wrong with my soft / hardware and how can I count microseconds *precisely*?

Comment: how can you handle 1us interrupts on 1MHz uC? It will never work.

Comment: Dang, of course you're right! `//OCR2 == 1, interupt will happen every 1 / 1000000 = 1us` is just not possible.

Comment: So what is the finest resolution I can get?

Comment: Calculate yourself  - how many ticks entry to the interrupt takes, how long the interrupt routine is executed and the exit overhead. But it will not be very reliable as you disable interrupts to make opertions atomic. So probably to avoid huge inaccuracies you need to multutiple this time by 3 or 4 probably. And I afraid you will be very close to .2 -.5ms. If you need microseconds to control for example software SPI - it will not work, you will need to find another sollution

Comment: @PeterJ Ok, so I followed your and the other comments below. Please, see the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this part of the code:

```
while (1) {
    if (timers_millis() % 1000 == 0) {
        leds_on(LEDS_REGISTER_PORT, LEDS_PORT_RIGHT);
    } else {
        leds_off(LEDS_REGISTER_PORT, LEDS_PORT_RIGHT);
    }
}
```

`timers_millis() % 1000` is only 0 for multiples of 1000. You turn the leds on for just one millisecond before turning them off again. What you would want is to take the millisecond counter modulo your desired period and then check whether the remainder is in the first half or the second half. For a period of 2 seconds, you'd need to check whether the remainder is in the first or second second:

```
if (timers_millis() % 2000 < 1000) // 0000..0999 ms
    // turn on
else                               // 1000..1999 ms
    // turn off
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess in this case the persistence of vision occurs. The LED seems to be on all the time. Still, I wonder - the code was running fine without the modifications and the time for LED to blink (probably, one clock cycle) was enough for me to detect it. Theoretically, nothing has changed this time, not in the blinking process. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

At 1 MHz CPU clock, and TIMER2 running at 1 MHz, you have 256 CPU cycles per timer overflow.

```
if (microseconds % 1000 == 0) {
    milliseconds++;
}
```

The `% 1000` will most likely require *much* more than 256 CPU cycles, so you will miss a couple of overflow interrupts. Plus, you will be spending almost all the CPU time in the ISR because the moment the ISR is finished the next overflow is already pending, instantly triggering the ISR again.

How about the following:

1. make a microsecond counter of `uint16_t`
2. in the timer's overflow ISR, do

   microseconds += 256;
   if ( microseconds >= 1000 ) {
     microseconds = microseconds - 1000;
     milliseconds++;
   }
3. timer_microseconds() returns `milliseconds * 1000 + microseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running your ave at 256Mhz or faster, you aren't getting 1us interrupt out of it.

Instead take a look of various timing implementations, like the arduino and see how sub us resolutions can be done.

I wrote about a set of routines (I can post the link later) but it essentially builds on a 32 bit over flow counter augmented by the timer counter itself.

Depending on the timer used, you get 16 ticks per us.